# findFragmentById returns null In specific activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to get the instance of my fragment to call some function inside it.
Unusually I'm getting null from the getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id) function.
However, in another activity, I can get the instance of the fragment with the same function getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id).

This is my not working Activity java:

```
public class SetMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public int imageId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_map);
        clearSelected(null);

        BoardFragment boardFragment = (BoardFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sm_fragment); // It will be null


        if(boardFragment.boardPositions.contains(R.drawable.sp)) // Null exception here
            findViewById(R.id.sp).setEnabled(false);
        if(boardFragment.boardPositions.contains(R.drawable.ep))
            findViewById(R.id.ep).setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

And this is the not working xml of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.SetMapActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/sm_fragment"
            android:name="com.example.user.myapplication.BoardFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_board"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to call `findViewById`, instead of `findFragmentById`?

Comment: No, I need the fragment instance not the view of the fragment. @diogenesgg

Comment: Does your Fragment extend `android.app.Fragment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are have extended `app.v4.Fragment` for `BoardFragment`. So for *support libraries* you should use :-

```
  getSupportFragmentManager() // instead of fragmentManager
```

So,

```
  BoardFragment boardFragment = (BoardFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sm_fragment);
```

Comment: It's android.app.Fragment do you have another idea?

Comment: can you post the import statements of class BoardFragment ?

Comment: Nvm I realized the problem :). that was the boardFragment.boardPositions that cause the nullPointer and i thought it was the findFragmentById. Anyway thank you for supporting :).